# Python - Compare filenames in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code which check if files contents are the same. Files have the same filename in both folders.
For example:

```
folder JSON1/test1.txt
folder JSON2/test1.txt
```

For a single file this works, but I would like to apply it to a list of files.
So in the JSON1 folder I will have:

```
JSON1 / test.txt
JSON1 / second.txt
JSON1 / result.txt
```

And in the JSON2 folder I will have the same file list.
Can you help how to change it to handle multiple files?

```
import os
import sys

filenameODS = "C:/Users/adm/Json1/" + sys.argv[1] + ".txt"
filenameDWH = "C:/Users/adm/Json2/" + sys.argv[1] + ".txt"

file1contents = set(open(filenameODS).readlines())
file2contents = set(open(filenameDWH).readlines())

if file1contents == file2contents:
    print("Files are the same!")
else:
    print("In file2, not file1:\n")
    for diffLine in file2contents - file1contents:
        print ("\t", diffLine)
    print ("\nIn file1, not file2:\n")
    for diffLine in file1contents - file2contents:
        print ("\t", diffLine)
    with open('C:/Users/adm/Json3/'+ sys.argv[1] + '.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(diffLine)
        f.close()
```

Comment: you're currently accepting filenames from arguments. do you mean you want add mutiple filenames from arguments?

Comment: no i want to create as filenameODS, filenameDWH access all files in a folder and save this to two lists.
I only tested it on one record, so I entered it as an argument

Comment: then you may need `os.walk` `glob`  and some for loops